# Sorting a JavaScript Object by specific property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

If I have a JavaScript object such as:

```
var currencies= {
  "EUR": 100, 
  "CHF": 15,
  "GPB": 75, 
  "JPN": 116, 
  "EUR": 12, 
  "JPN": 15, 
  "USD": 55, 
  "CHF": 22,
  "USD": 100, 
};
```

Is there a way to sort them in this specific order?

```
var currencies= {
  "EUR": 12, 
  "EUR": 100, 
  "USD": 55, 
  "USD": 100, 
  "GPB": 75, 
  "CHF": 15,
  "CHF": 22,
  "JPN": 15, 
  "JPN": 116, 
};
```

Comment: Why sort an object in the first place?

Comment: That's an invalid object due to duplicated keys; you don't have an object like shown

Comment: Object keys are unsorted by design. If you need order use Array or Map.

Comment: List of objects, my mistake

Comment: please add the sorting rule and the real array, you have.

Comment: First by the following rule("EUR","USD","GBP","CHF","JPN") and than by the value

Comment: If you just type this in the console you will see that the object is invalid and you will lose values of duplicated keys. Also object keys are unsortable right now, you need an array.

Answer (score 0):

By having an array with objects with a single key/value pair, you could take this pair for sorting by key and then by value.

```js
var currencies= [{ EUR: 100 }, { CHF: 15 }, { GPB: 75 }, { JPN: 116 }, { EUR: 12 }, { JPN: 15 }, { USD: 55 }, { CHF: 22 }, { USD: 100 }],
    order = { EUR: 1, USD: 2, GBP: 3, CHF: 4, JPN: 5 };

currencies.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = Object.entries(a)[0],
        bb = Object.entries(b)[0];

    return order[aa[0]] - order[bb[0]] || aa[1] - bb[1];
});

console.log(currencies);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```